# What did the 'new' parameter in numpy's histogram() function do?

Tags: python, numpy, legacy-code

I stumbled across some [old code](https://github.com/aarchiba/kuiper/blob/master/anderson_darling.py) (>10 years) and one of the lines reads:

```
c, be = np.histogram(s, bins=values, new=True)
```

This `new` parameter is [no longer there](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html). I'm trying to make this code work, but I've no idea what that `new` parameter did. I haven't found anything about it online. I could just remove it, but then I wouldn't know what it was used for and if it was perhaps something important.

Can anybody tell me what this parameter did and how can it be reproduced now?

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.3.x/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html?highlight=histogram#numpy.histogram.  TLDR it was removed in `1.4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That argument allowed the older version to provide bin creation functionality equal to that of newer versions (>= 1.3). I found the following note in code at this [link](https://cmssdt.cern.ch/lxr/source/RecoLuminosity/LumiDB/python/mpl_axes_hist_fix.py)

> Either an integer number of bins or a sequence giving the
>    bins.  If *bins* is an integer, *bins* + 1 bin edges
>    will be returned, consistent with :func:`numpy.histogram`
>    for numpy version >= 1.3, and with the *new* = True argument
>    in earlier versions.

And this from the docs linked in the comment:

> new : {None, True, False}, optional
>
> Whether to use the new semantics for histogram:
>
> - None : the new behaviour is used, no warning is printed.
> - True : the new behaviour is used and a warning is raised about the future removal of the new keyword.
> - False : the old behaviour is used and a DeprecationWarning is raised.
>
> As of NumPy 1.3, this keyword should not be used explicitly since it will disappear in NumPy 1.4.

Comment: So it appears that it can indeed be removed with no unexpected consequences. Thank you!